# Object Reference Error while trying to put <hr> tag in stringBuilderObject.Append() VB.net

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

My main aim is to underline some words in pdf with blue color using VB.net. The code is shown below:

```
strSignHTML.Append("<TD class=""TBLDATA"" width=""25%"" align=left><br /><br>")
strSignHTML.Append("<hr color=""midnightblue"">")
strSignHTML.Append("</TD>")
strSignHTML.Append("<td width=50%>&nbsp;</td>")
strSignHTML.Append("<td class=""TBLDATA"" width=""25%"" align=left> <br>")
strSignHTML.Append("<hr color=""midnightblue"">")
strSignHTML.Append("</td>")
strSignHTML.Append("</tr>")
strSignHTML.Append("<tr>")
strSignHTML.Append("<td class=""TBLDATA"">")
strSignHTML.Append("<font color=""midnightblue""><b>Signature</b></font>")
strSignHTML.Append("</td>")
strSignHTML.Append("<td width=50%>&nbsp;</td>")
strSignHTML.Append("<td class=""TBLDATA"">")
strSignHTML.Append("<font color=""midnightblue""><b>Date</b></font>")
strSignHTML.Append("</td>")
strSignHTML.Append("</tr>")
strSignHTML.Append("<tr>")
```

Comment: And where did you create your `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Maybe because `stringBuilderObject` was never initialized ...

Comment: That all is done, without the hr tags it is working fine, this is just the part of code where hr tags are used

Comment: Just a note: For those kind of stuffs i would rather use `<![CDATA[content]]>` [XML CDATA Literal (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xml-literals/xml-cdata-literal) . In that case you dont need to worry about quote marks

Comment: thanks @programerAnel I will do thaat! but do you have any solution for the main problem I am having?

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), namely, how and where you initialize the `StringBuilder` variable. For us to be able to help you we must be able to identify the problem, preferably (and most efficiently) by reproducing it ourselves. Appending a constant string doesn't cause an NRE unless the string builder variable is not initialized. Create a new project and recreate the relevant parts of your code as accurately as possible, then if that still reproduces the problem post that code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do import library

```
Imports System.Text
```

And actually set the  `strSignHTML` as `StringBuilder` you are good to go

```
    Dim strSignHTML As New StringBuilder
    strSignHTML.Append("<TD class=""TBLDATA"" width=""25%"" align=left><br /><br>")
    strSignHTML.Append("<hr color=""midnightblue"">")
    strSignHTML.Append("</TD>")
    strSignHTML.Append("<td width=50%>&nbsp;</td>")
    strSignHTML.Append("<td class=""TBLDATA"" width=""25%"" align=left> <br>")
    strSignHTML.Append("<hr color=""midnightblue"">")
    strSignHTML.Append("</td>")
    strSignHTML.Append("</tr>")
    strSignHTML.Append("<tr>")
    strSignHTML.Append("<td class=""TBLDATA"">")
    strSignHTML.Append("<font color=""midnightblue""><b>Signature</b></font>")
    strSignHTML.Append("</td>")
    strSignHTML.Append("<td width=50%>&nbsp;</td>")
    strSignHTML.Append("<td class=""TBLDATA"">")
    strSignHTML.Append("<font color=""midnightblue""><b>Date</b></font>")
    strSignHTML.Append("</td>")
    strSignHTML.Append("</tr>")
    strSignHTML.Append("<tr>")

    Dim myString As String = strSignHTML.ToString
```

Even so i would rather use [CDATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xml-literals/xml-cdata-literal)

```
Dim myString As String = <![CDATA[
                <TD class="TBLDATA" width="25%" align=left><br /><br>
                <hr color="midnightblue">
                </TD>
                <td width=50%>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="TBLDATA" width="25%" align=left> <br>
                <hr color="midnightblue">
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="TBLDATA">
                <font color = "midnightblue"><b>Signature</b></font>
                </td>
                <td width = 50% >& nbsp;</td>
                <td class="TBLDATA">
                <font color = "midnightblue"><b>Date</b></font>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>]]>.Value
```